# if $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = \infty$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty}(-a_n)=-\infty$

Tags: convergence-divergence, proof-writing

if $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = \infty$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty}(-a_n)=-\infty$

I know I need to multiply by -1 to get $-a_n$ but I don't know how to formally write this proof.

Comment: Do you know what it means formally that $\lim a_n=\pm\infty$?

Comment: It means that $a_n$ diverges to $\pm \infty$

Comment: Take a look at answers, that's not a formal definition.

Comment: @KellyR "formally".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ means that for any (arbitrarily large) $L\in\Bbb R$ there is an $n$ so that $a_n>L$, i.e. $a_n$ exceeds any bound.

Now if you choose a very small (i.e. very negative) number $S\in\Bbb R$, then $-S$ is very big and we can find an $n$ so that $a_n>-S$. We can multiply this by $-1$ and find $-a_n<S$. And this is exactly what $\lim_{n\to\infty}-a_n=-\infty$ means: for any $S\in\Bbb R$ you can find an $n$ so that $-a_n<S$. The sequence $-a_n$ goes below any bound.

---

Here I will try to give a proof with more words. Maybe this makes more clear what is going on.

When a sequence diverges to $\infty$, this has a concrete mathematical meaning. It means that it grows and grows and does not stay below any bound. Imagine a number. The sequence will finally exceed this number. Now imagine this sequence as a graph. You see a curve rising. Now flip the curve at the $x$-axis. This gives $-a_n$. Now the sequence is below zero and gets smaller and smaller. Imagine any (negative) number. The sequence will finally go below this number. And this is *exactly* what is meant when saying that it diverges to $-\infty$.

Comment: My current proof states: Suppose $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$, then there' some $M \in \mathbb N$ where $M>0$ and $n \geq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Now suppose that $-1 * \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$, i.e. $ \lim_{n \to \infty} (-a_n) = -\infty$. I'm not sure I can assume this though. The beginning pieces to my proof are the same beginning pieces my professor includes in every proof, however they have not explained to us what these pieces mean and do not always use them even when they state them in the proof.

Comment: @Kelly Sorry this is very confusing. First: "$n\geq M$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$" is probably not what you want to say. Though I have no idea what you want to say. There is only one such $M$ and it is zero. Consider my first line. Is that what you want to say? Second: No, you cannot assume this.

Comment: Okay I have read through your explanation (thank you by the way!), I have rewritten: Suppose $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$ then for any limit,$L$, there is an $n$ so that $a_n>L$. Similarly, to show the sequence goes below any bound, consider $a_n>L$ and multiply by $-1$, i.e. $-a_n<-L$, thus for any $-L$ there is an $n$ so that $-a_n<-L$, i.e. $ \lim_{n \to \infty}(-a_n)=- \infty$

Comment: @Kelly Looks better. Note: $L$ is no limit, but just a real number.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will change the limit part.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$, i.e. $\forall L \exists N \forall n>N:a_n>L$.

We now have to prove $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (-a_n) = -\infty$, i.e. $\forall L \exists N \forall n>N:-a_n<L$.

This is trivial.